# Transit Visa request from Kuwait to Croatia with passport less than 6 month to go

Tags: visas, transit, kuwait, croatian-citizens

I need to apply through my agent for visa to travel from Kuwait to Croatia in the beginning of September. My intention is to apply on Sunday 26th.

I have signed on the vessel permanently located in Kuwait on 23rd June 18 and signing off in the end of next week. Is it going to be any problem for transit visa to exit Kuwait with Croatian passport expiry 04.02.2019?

Comment: If you're already in Kuwait, why would you need a transit visa for Kuwait?

Comment: The point is that on the way from airport to the vessel passport is stamped with entry and exit and each time i am leaving the vessel for whatsoever reason i need to applicate for entry visa in this case from the vessel to the airport

Answer (score 2):

No.

Airline Crewmembers and seamen are given special status for visa processing. You will not have any issues.